# React Native Jest Syntax Error: Unterminated Regular Expression

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, babel-jest

I'm getting this strange syntax error whilst running a simple test for a Todo demo I'm writing. I have added the code and test in the same file so that you can see what's going on.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

const TodoItem = () => {
  return(
    <Text>{Hello}</Text>
  );
};

export default TodoItem;

describe('<TodoItem', () => {
  it('should update uncompleted task to complete when pressed', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<TodoItem />)
  });
});
```

### Test Result

Run: `jest`

```
 FAIL  __tests__/components/TodoItem.spec.tsx
  ● Test suite failed to run

    SyntaxError: /Users/jonesagyemang/Projects/side/Todoist/__tests__/components/TodoItem.spec.tsx: Unterminated regular expression (7:19)

       5 | const TodoItem = () => {
       6 |   return(
    >  7 |     <Text>{Hello}</Text>
         |                    ^
       8 |   );
       9 | };
      10 |

      at Object.raise (../../../../../usr/local/lib/node_modules/jest/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:6322:17)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.2s
Ran all test suites related to changed files.

Watch Usage: Press w to show more.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming it's a text that you want to display with `Text` component. Try removing the `{}` for the Hello since it isn't a variable or a function in your code.

```
const TodoItem = () => {
  return(
    <Text>Hello</Text>
  );
};
```

Comment: I tried that but, that doesn't work. In fact, initially the curly braces wasn't around it. I only put it there just to experiment.